# Is this sentence structure a valid usage?

Tags: sentence-patterns

At one point in my story, I am trying to describe a fight. The action is that one of the fighters firsts attacks with a sword, disarming his opponent and then hits him with his foot.

The sentence is -

> The blade flashed, the strike removing the sword from his hands.
>   Charlie **followed that with a lash of his foot**, tripping Adam
>   off his.

The text in bold is the one which feels very weird to me when reading. Is it a valid usage ? If not, what can I do to make the action more sensible.

Comment: "lash" is not a word I would normally associate with a foot.

Comment: The *sentence structure* seems ok.

Comment: @Cascabel: I have read it in a lot of novels and it does appear to be a regular usage - https://www.google.com/search?q="lashed+out+with+his+foot"&tbm=bks

Comment: All of those usages seem to be the 2-word verb _lash out_ with "foot". That is a little different.

Comment: How is "lash" not a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the word "lash" to denote movement, it almost always refers to something pliable like a tail, whip, rain, etc. 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lash

It seems like you would be better served by something closer to a definition of "hit" or "strike":
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/strike

However, the english language itself is pliable or fluid, so use that artistic license!

Comment: I support your answer but please take the time to include pertinent citations sourced at your links. Thank you.

Comment: @SciGuy: strike is a great suggestion. I guess that could also work out